# cannot connect to VM in azure

Tags: windows, azure

this is the first time I am trying to host at Iaas level using microsoft azure. I have created a VM, microsoft server 2012.  But I cannot access the VM using the DNS name.

Comment: Are you trying to access the VM via RDP or another protocol?

Comment: No. I am just trying to access my website hosted in the VM, I am using apache server.

Comment: Have you created the required endpoints, what is the error or response code you're getting?

Comment: I am trying to host at Iaas level for the first time. I have created endpoints for http and https, hope that is sufficient. I am trying to access using the DNS name for the VM. The error says 'webpage is not available'. I know I might be sounding foolish..sorry.

Comment: OK, are you able to browse it locally from the VM via RDP? If so please check if the port you're hosting on is LISTENING.

Comment: In general, what you have to do is making your private ports available. If you have a web page hosted in the local IIS, you have to add these endpoints in the management portal. The private port is your local port and the public port is the one from where you can access the private port (they can be different if you want).

Comment: did you open up you firewall settings on your VM to allow outbound traffic on your VM, the endpoints is one thing, opening them up at VM side is another :-) , so you need to enable the IIS Firewall rules to allow the outbound and inbound (they pre-exist btw)

Comment: IIS is disabled and I am using apache server

Comment: Maybe take this thread into a chat room? This isn't the place for such a discussion, as it looks like a debugging session buried in comments. Plus, since it's not programming-related, this question should be migrated to ServerFault or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the content of the comments, I see three things that could be wrong

1) Apache is not listening on the external IP of the VM

2) Firewall is not configured to allow for access

3) Since you mentioned DNS, is that the *.cloudapp.net hostname or a custom DNS? If it's the latter, maybe it isn't distributed yet or misconfigured?

Which of these did you check already? Then we can guide you through the remaining ones.

Comment: I have tried both configuring the firewall and then since it didn't work, tried disabling the firewall. The dns is with .cloudapp.net. Apache does not seem to listen to external IP of the VM.

Comment: Then the solution is easy, just configure Apache to listen to either only the external IP or all of them (which should be preferable in most cases)

Comment: Thanks very much everyone. Its working now. It was an issue with setting up the  endpoints